# Creating and Running an Application Client on the GlassFish Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

Because [this example of Creating and Running an Application Client on the GlassFish Server](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html) fails to launch, I filed bugs with Netbeans and Glassfish:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=247484

https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21215

**How do I run the appclient?**

I followed the [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html) to build the EAR.  It deploys as expected:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin list-applications
Nothing to list.
No applications are deployed to this target server.
Command list-applications executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$       
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin deploy NetBeansProjects/EntAppEJB/dist/EntAppEJB.ear 
Application deployed with name EntAppEJB.
Command deploy executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin list-applications
EntAppEJB  <ear, appclient, ejb>  
Command list-applications executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$
```

[The JNLP file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5hKxkS1VyAxeU11UGd4T2pYd1k/edit?usp=sharing) for Java Web Start (JWS) launches and downloads as documented:

[image]

clicking "launch" downloads [the JNLP](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5hKxkS1VyAxeU11UGd4T2pYd1k/edit?usp=sharing):

```
thufir@dur:~$  
thufir@dur:~$ ll Downloads/EntAppClient 
-rw-r--r-- 1 thufir thufir 40314 Sep 26 10:20 Downloads/EntAppClient
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ mv Downloads/EntAppClient Downloads/EntAppClient.jnlp
thufir@dur:~$
```

as per the Glassfish documentation:

> Java Web Start
>
> Java Web Start allows your application client to be
>   easily launched and automatically downloaded and updated. It is
>   enabled for all application clients by default. For more information,
>   see Using Java Web Start.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition
Application Development Guide Release 4.0
page 172

and

> Downloading and Launching an Application Client
>
> If Java Web Start is
>   enabled for your deployed application client, you can launch it for
>   testing. Simply click on the Launch button next to the application
>   client or application's listing on the App Client Modules page in the
>   Administration Console.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition
Application Development Guide Release 4.0
page 176

However, [the JNLP fails to execute](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u1K53bSY947WrrWtEV81Qrz-QME4xFGwGItzPuhXsOk/edit?usp=sharing):

[image: UserError: ACC007]

error:

```
org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.UserError: ACC007: The app client file /___JWSappclient/___app/EntAppEJB/EntAppEJBClient/EntAppClientClient.jar does not contain a manifest; the app client container cannot process it.  Embedded programs should pass URIs with scheme "jar:" for JAR files and scheme "file:" for directories.
```

Note that the error is in regards to `EntAppClientClient.jar` and not `EntAppClient.jar`.

What additional information can I provide in the bug reports?  I'll, at a minimum, link to this question and add [the JNLP](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5hKxkS1VyAxeU11UGd4T2pYd1k/edit?usp=sharing) and the [log of javaws](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u1K53bSY947WrrWtEV81Qrz-QME4xFGwGItzPuhXsOk/edit?usp=sharing) running it.  What else would be useful?

The Glassfish log, or at least a portion:

```
[2014-09-26T10:25:29.424-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.container.appclient] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1411752329424] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Adapter[/___JWSappclient/___app/EntAppEJB] EntAppEJBClient/EntAppClientClient.jar
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.servedcontent.StreamedAutoSignedStaticContent.process(StreamedAutoSignedStaticContent.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.RestrictedContentAdapter.processContent(RestrictedContentAdapter.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.RestrictedContentAdapter.serviceContent(RestrictedContentAdapter.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.AppClientHTTPAdapter.service(AppClientHTTPAdapter.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
]]

[2014-09-26T10:25:29.709-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [NCLS-CORE-00091] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=24 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1411752329709] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to set customized error page
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
]]
```

Comment: see also: https://java.net/projects/glassfish/lists/users/archive/2014-09/message/70

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using glassfish 3.1 and jdk 1.7_10 this does not need signed your applications. 
I recommend this or signing your applications to work in jdk 1.7 update 45 or later.
greetings from Mexico

Comment: interesting.  Do you have direct experience with Glassfish Application Client?  It doesn't seem to be widely used.

Comment: I have experience in a productive development in glassfish. It is not currently used. there is not much documentation online.

Comment: thx.  that was my concern: in general, that it's just not used.

Comment: Greetings friend happy development yupiii